# Migrating Docker container to a new server

Tags: docker, yaml, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have been using a docker hosted CRM called Corteza.
I have outgrown my old VPS and moved over to a new dedicated sever and transferred all of my docker containers over.
I use docker to host 4 other apps and managed to transfer easily by copying the YAML and env files to the new server and also moving the volumes over, each container worked perfectly with the exception of Corteza.

I have used the exact same YAML and env files and for the life of me cannot figure out what the issue is.

I have sent them multiple messages through various different avenues and am yet to hear back so I hoped someone on here might be able to help.

The container is produced, but when I navigate to the address, this is what I see...

[image]

In plesk, I have set the docker proxy rules for api-corteza.domain.co.uk to access port 30080 and corteza.domain.co.uk to access port 30080 and set the DNS records for each domain to point to my server IP.

My YAML file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
db:
image: percona:8.0
restart: on-failure
environment:
# To be picked up by percona image when creating the database
# Must match with DB_DSN settings inside .env
MYSQL_DATABASE: DB
MYSQL_USER: DB
MYSQL_PASSWORD: PWD
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PWD
# healthcheck: { test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "IP"], timeout: 20s, retries: 10 }
# Uncomment to use local fs for data persistence
volumes: [ "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql" ]
networks: [ internal ]

server:
image: cortezaproject/corteza-server:2020.12
restart: on-failure
env_file: [ .env ]
environment:
# Informing Corredor where it he contact us
CORREDOR_ADDR: "corredor:80"
VIRTUAL_HOST: "https://corteza.domain.com"
depends_on: [ db, corredor ]
volumes: [ "./data/server:/data" ]
healthcheck: { test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"], timeout: 20s, retries: 10 }
ports: [ "127.0.0.1:30080:80" ]
networks: [ internal ]

corredor:
image: cortezaproject/corteza-server-corredor:2020.12
restart: on-failure
env_file: [ .env ]
environment:
# Informing Corredor where it he contact us
CORREDOR_ADDR: "corredor:80"
# Binds internal port to port LOCAL_DEMO_CRD_PORT on localhost
networks: [ internal ]
volumes: [ "./corredor:/corredor/usr" ]

webapp:
image: cortezaproject/corteza-webapp:2020.12
restart: on-failure
depends_on: [ server ]
environment:
# Monolith server in the backend, all services can be found under one base URL
MONOLITH_API: 1
# Configure web application with API location
API_BASEURL: "api-corteza.domain.com"
VIRTUAL_HOST: corteza.domain.com
ports: [ "127.0.0.1:30081:80" ]

networks:
internal: {}
```

My ENV file

```
# Version of Corteza Docker images
Domain=corteza.domain.com (Tried changing this to IP but made no difference)
VERSION=2020.12
`# Database connection` `DB_DSN=db details` `AUTH_JWT_SECRET=secret` `LOG_LEVEL=info`
CORREDOR_EXT_SEARCH_PATHS=/extensions:/extensions/*:/corredor/usr:/corredor/usr/*
CORREDOR_EXEC_CSERVERS_API_HOST=api-corteza.domain.com
CORREDOR_EXEC_CSERVERS_API_BASEURL_TEMPLATE=https://{host}/{service}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have no idea where to look to debug the issue.

---

The problem appears to be Percona,
I am thinking that it is something to do with the image communicating with the main server.
When I run docker-compose ps all images are running but Percona is constantly restarting

Logs

```
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2022-07-04T17:54:35.904588Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28-20) initializing of server in progress as process 15
2022-07-04T17:54:35.907285Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010460] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
2022-07-04T17:54:35.907299Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2022-07-04T17:54:35.907378Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-07-04T17:54:35.907726Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-20)  Percona Server (GPL), Release 20, Revision fd4b5a776a6.
```

Comment: Your yaml file is missing the required indentation.